# redline errors in CODE for F# MVC

Tags: .net, f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I just run `dotnet new mvc -lang F#` and got the template created.

Once i run it using `dotnet run` it runs smoothly without errors.

But, in MS Code, I see lots of error-like msgs, and lots of red lines, how to get red of them?

[image]

I got the below error in the `output`:

> [18:18:28 INFO ] Logging to output at level INFO. If you want detailed
>   messages, try level DEBUG. [18:18:30 INFO ] listening notification on
>   /notify started [18:18:30 INFO ] listening notification on
>   /notifyWorkspace started [18:18:30 ERROR] Cannot execute
>   simplifiedNames, File 'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\Startup.fs' not
>   parsed  [18:18:30 ERROR] Cannot execute unusedOpens, File
>   'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\Startup.fs' not parsed  [18:18:30
>   ERROR] Cannot execute unusedDeclarations, File
>   'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\Startup.fs' not parsed  [18:18:30
>   ERROR] Cannot execute lint, File
>   'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\Startup.fs' not parsed  [18:18:30
>   ERROR] Project loading failed, The system cannot find the file
>   specified 'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\App.fsproj' [18:18:31 ERROR]
>   Project loading failed, The system cannot find the file specified
>   'c:\Users\YousefH\Documents\App\App.fsproj'

[image]

Note: I do not have mono installed, but have `fsc.exe`, and the company policy not allowing installing mono

Comment: if you view output (in view menu or ctrl + k, ctrl +h ) do you see any error messages?

Comment: @Stewart_R NO ERRORS THERE

Comment: @Stewart_R sorry, I got some error, I'll update the question now

Comment: @Stewart_R note I do not have mono installed, but have `fsc.exe`